Is there a way to program a function into a TI-84 which takes an inline parameter, calculates a return, and substitutes that the result in that line?
I want to create a program in my TI-84 that allows me to quickly generate unit complex-numbers given an angle x (that is, generate cos(x) + isin(x)), essentially so I can do 2 dimensional vector math with minimal effort, ex.
3cmplx(30) + 5cmplx(270) = 15/√2 - 7i/2
The TI-84 does not appear to have this feature (at least, such a function is not located with the rest of the complex numbers functions)
I know how to create programs which can execute these steps, and I know that you can use dummy variables such as X to store the results of these programs, but to maximize my laziness, I want to create a method which behaves like the built in formulae of the TI-84, being able to freely slot them in to lines of operations.
I have played around with the I/I features in the program menu, and as of yet I have not found a means to achieve this, but before ruling it out as impossible, I wanted to ask for assistance on Stack-Exchange.

Does it not have an exp function for complex numbers? Something like exp(ix) = cos(x) + i.sin(x)(argument by default in radians but can probably be in degrees or grads).

@MartinBrown Sadly no, at least not when I look at the catalog of functions.
